# Active Directory Using spring security

Tags: spring

**My requirement was. i have one login page which has spring security. first i want to authenticate username and password with active directory,if user exist then i need to check only username in database.**

I have tried online for LDAP authentication using spring security.. but i am not able to find exactly how to achieve this.. can any body help on this..

Comment: what is the problem with your current code? be specific and give details.

Comment: actually i dont have any code for authenticating ActiveDirectory users using spring security.. can you help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to inject a custom implementation of LdapAuthenticator. I have done something similar but in an old project since 3 years you may have to change the code. Basically we do something like this (Read comments carefully) :

```
import org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextAdapter;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextOperations;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticator;


public class LdapAuthenticatorImpl implements LdapAuthenticator {

    private DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextFactory;
    private String principalPrefix = "";

    public DirContextOperations authenticate(Authentication authentication) {

            // Grab the username and password out of the authentication object.
            String principal = principalPrefix + authentication.getName();
            String password = "";
            if (authentication.getCredentials() != null) {
                    password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
            }

            // If we have a valid username and password, try to authenticate.
            if (!("".equals(principal.trim())) && !("".equals(password.trim()))) {
                    InitialLdapContext ldapContext = (InitialLdapContext) contextFactory.getReadWriteContext();

                    //We attempt the super class authentication which will validate the credentials. In case 
                    //of success it will return an instance of authAdapter otherwise it will throw BadCredentialsException.
                    DirContextOperations authAdapter = super.authenticate(authentication) ;
                    //We can consider authentication successful with LDAP.

                    //TODO check the user in the database


                    //
                    return authAdapter;
            } else {
                    throw new BadCredentialsException("Blank username and/or password!");
            }
    }
}
```

In the configuration file you need to override the existing bean called ldapAuthenticator with your implementation. The below example in grails syntax but you can do the same in application-descriptor.xml :

```
    ldapAuthenticator(CustomBindAuthenticator, ref('contextSource')) {
        userSearch = ref('ldapUserSearch')
    }
```

you can also configure it in the xml like this :

```
<bean id="ldapAuthenticator" class="com.mypackage.myClass">
      <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
      <property name="userSearch" ref="ldapUserSearch"/>
   </bean>
```

Comment: not clear.. can you give me how to configure in spring-security.xml file

Comment: Ok.. my actual req is when ever user login into application, first we need to check weather entered username and password in Active Directory or not,if user exist then check weather user exist in the database or not only through username but not with password. if user not exist in Active directory we need to raise error user not found in AD. if user not exist in the database we need to raise error user not found in database

Comment: Please check the code .. I have left a comment in the place where you need to fetch the username from DB.

Comment: ok but is above with spring security.. what about spring security file

Comment: I don't have a full working example because I usually use the Grails spring security plugin which is a kind of wrapper of it. The configuration file that I have are all in Groovy language not xml.